# Jquery Hide Function not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Very simply, the ".hide()" function is not working. I am using the jquery-rails gem and I have the proper statements in application.js.

Here is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

<script> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
      $("#ld").hide();
      //alert('Hooray!');
   });
});
</script>
```

In layouts/application.html.erb I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>

      <%# two lines below allow for device-responsive formatting, see twitter-bootstrap    page%>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag :highcharts %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
   </head>

   <body>
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
      <div class="container">
         <%= yield %>
         <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
         <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

1) If I change change to this, hide() still doesn't work. I also clearly see assets/jquery.js when viewing the page source in my browser.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

2) In the HTML I have:

```
<div id="#ld">
  <%= image_tag("ajax-loader.gif", :alt => "test image") %>
</div>
```

Comment: .css() does not work either...where would I find these definitions when viewing the page source?

Comment: Can you please put include the resulting HTML instead of some ruby template. I cannot find where your tag with id "ld" is supposed to be...

Comment: Do you have jQuery included? Your HTML only shows the jQuery UI script.

Comment: Before you ask any question about something not working in JS, check the JS console. does it show an error?

Comment: There are some errors:

Comment: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css"

bootst...ive.css

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://127.0.0.1:3000/resources/demos/style.css"

style.css

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://127.0.0.1:3000/resources/demos/style.css"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `#` hash from your div's id:

```
<div id="ld">
```

The hash you only put into CSS and jQuery sizzle selectors to say that you are looking for an id as opposed to a class (`.`) or tag name (no prefix).